# Python 3: NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to run an Elastic Net regression but get the following error:  NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined... any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

```
    # ElasticNet Regression 

    from sklearn import linear_model
    import statsmodels.api as sm

    ElasticNet = sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet() # create a lasso instance
    ElasticNet.fit(X_train, y_train) # fit data

    # print(lasso.coef_)
    # print (lasso.intercept_) # print out the coefficients

    print ("R^2 for training set:"),
    print (ElasticNet.score(X_train, y_train))

    print ('-'*50)

    print ("R^2 for test set:"),
    print (ElasticNet.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Use `linear_model.ElasticNet()`. Drop `sklearn`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have imported `linear_model`

Change

`ElasticNet = sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet()`

to

`ElasticNet = linear_model.ElasticNet()`